# the_content() wordpress creates unwanted top space

Tags: html, css, wordpress

i apologize for this basic question; been trying to solve this myself but still failed.

1) whenever i add `the_content()` inside a `div` or any markup like `<h1`>, it creates a space at top; i have tried adding `margin:0; padding:0;` on the `markup` where it contains `the_content()`.

2) added `remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );` on my functions.php

Id love to post the source, but its too long. but the basic layout i want shows below. i just want to remove the space in between the `title` div and `content` div.

```
HTML -----------------------------------------------------  
 <div id="main">
   <div id="title"> <?php the_author() ?> </div>

   <div id="content">  <?php the_content(); ?> </div>

 </div>

CSS -----------------------------------------------------

 #title {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    }
 #content {
    background:#dcdcdc;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    }
 #content h1 {
    font-size:250%;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    }
```

The result looks like:

[image]

editted:

Comment: Whats the CSS of your `#title` element?

Comment: also i tried adding `p, br {margin:0; padding0;}` but the space on top of `content` div still shows; i even placed all `divs` on my markup a `margin:0; padding:0;` not sure if this is a bug tho.

Answer (score 0):

Unwanted space must be caused by either an extra P, BR, other element or margin or padding, or an old crappy browser that rendered margins wrong.  You'd help us out a lot more if you'd tell us which problem is the culprit.  Look at the source code of the HTML page.  Is there an extra P or BR between the elements?

If there isn't, then the problem might be an !important keyword in the CSS that's overriding your own styles.